# tic tac toe game logic

Tags: java, android

I don't understand the game *Tic Tac Toe*. I've just started learning Android and followed a course that starts very easy, but now I am stuck at this game. Please, help me.

I am stuck at this code. Can any one explain me what is going on there?

```
for (int[] columnWinner : winner) {

        if (playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] &&
                playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[2]] &&
                playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] != Player.NO) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We have Winner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }
```

This is the full code and it worked perfectly, without any errors.

```
Player currentPlayer = Player.ONE;
Player[] playerChoices = new Player[9];
int[][] winner = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    playerChoices[0] = Player.NO;
    playerChoices[1] = Player.NO;
    playerChoices[2] = Player.NO;
    playerChoices[3] = Player.NO;
    playerChoices[4] = Player.NO;
    playerChoices[5] = Player.NO;
    playerChoices[6] = Player.NO;
    playerChoices[7] = Player.NO;
    playerChoices[8] = Player.NO;


}

public void imageViewIsTapped(View imageView) {

    ImageView tappedImage = (ImageView) imageView;

    tappedImage.setTranslationX(-2000);

    int tiTag = Integer.parseInt(tappedImage.getTag().toString());
    playerChoices[tiTag] = currentPlayer;

    if (currentPlayer == Player.ONE) {

        tappedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiger);

        currentPlayer = Player.TWO;
    } else if (currentPlayer == Player.TWO) {

        tappedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.lion);

        currentPlayer = Player.ONE;
    }


    for (int[] columnWinner : winner) {


        if (playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] &&
                playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[2]] &&
                playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] != Player.NO) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We have Winner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }


    tappedImage.animate().translationXBy(2000).alpha(1).rotation(3600).setDuration(1000);


}


enum Player {

    ONE, TWO, NO
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Syed! welcome to Stack Overflow. I cant actually see that you've asked a question - tell us what you have tried and how you've attempted to fix it. If you are getting an error, post the logcat and error code so we can try to help :)

Comment: i have not any error in my code i am just want explanation how the code flow is working in for loop which i mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[][] winner = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}};
```

This is all possible cases when there is a winner. The first 3 is horizontal, the next 3 is vertical, the last 2 is diagonal, where the numbers are defined like this, indicated in the previous code:

```
 0 | 1 | 2
---+---+---
 3 | 4 | 5
---+---+---
 6 | 7 | 8
```

Then let's analyse the core code:

```
for (int[] columnWinner : winner) { // traverses all cases
    if ( // if there is a case satisfied
       // for a specified case for example {0, 1, 2}
        playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] && // check if choice at 0 is the same as choice at 1
        playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[2]] && // check if choice at 1 is the same as choice at 2
        // then choice at 0 1 2 are the same
        playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] != Player.NO // and this "the same" is not "they are all empty"
    ) { 
    // then there is a winner
```

Comment: i have a problem in this statement  can you please explain in detail if (playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] && playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[2]]

Comment: Thank you sir now i am understood, Thank you \

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are asking about the for each loop:

```
for (int[] columnWinner : winner) {
```

The loop is called a for each loop that creates a variable and gives it a value for every iteration in the loop.

In this case, the loop creates an array of length 3 named columnWinner for each possible row, column, and diagonal on the tic-tac-toe board.

Each time through the loop, it checks whether the person has won be verifying if all three elements in the columnWinner array are the same:

```
if (playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] && playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[2]]
```

And then checking to make sure they are filled in, instead of empty.

```
&& playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] != Player.NO) {
```

Comment: What is three elements

Comment: if (playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] && playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[2]]

Comment: i did not understand about this condition

Answer (score 0):

The 3 x 3 board is represented (rather strangely) by a one-dimensional array.  All winning positions were determined by hand and listed in the `winner` array, in triples because it takes 3 markers to occupy a winnng position in tic-tac-toe.

The loop you indicate is checked each of those winning positions in turn.

For example, consider winning position `{1, 4, 7}`.  The if-statement is checking whether the values at board positions 1, 4, 7 are identical and not equal to the 'NO' value which says no-one has played there.

The actual `winners` data is structured as an array of (3-element) arrays; so the for-loop takes each 3-element array at a time and uses it to drive the 'if' statement.  For example, when `columnWinner` is `{1, 4, 7}` then `columnWinner[0]` is 4, and thus `playerChoices[columnWinner[0]]` is looking at `playerChoices[4]`.

Comment: please explain this condition if (playerChoices[columnWinner[0]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] && playerChoices[columnWinner[1]] == playerChoices[columnWinner[2]